# How can I post on Super User using Tor?

Tags: google, captcha, botnet

I continue to get the message

> Your post cannot be submitted at this time due to the volume of spam and abuse originating from your network. We apologize for any inconvenience. See the help center for more.

upon attempting to post a question on Superuser.

I have had a Stackexchange account for several years, however I just recently joined the Super User community. I seem to be primarliy having this issue with Super User.
How can I get around this, to post my question on Super User.

It is also impossible to message the support about it, as it requires a Google Captcha and the Captcha states it is getting too many automated requests to process.

Comment: Change your exit node and try again a few times. If they don't want to allow Tor users, then you can't post with Tor.

Comment: Changing the exit node seems to make no difference. I'm curious why this is the scenario with ONLY Super User.. My understanding was each community is still part of the stack exchange website, hence, using the same servers and infrastructure. As communities are created on-the-fly. Didn't think mods, etc. would have this much control per community.